# Audio Synthesis in Javascript: Can I use an oscillator node to adjust the frequency of a biquad filter?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I've been experimenting with sound design in the web audio API, and run into a point of frustration: I'd like to connect an oscillator to the frequency value on a lowpass biquad filter, which can easily be done to a gain node's gain value. Thus far, I've had no success, but no helpful error messages, either.

```
var ctx = new window.webkitAudioContext();
var currentKeysDown = [];

var filter = ctx.createBiquadFilter();
filter.connect(ctx.destination);
filter.type = 'lowpass';
filter.frequency.value = 400;

var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
osc.connect(filter);
osc.type = 'square';
osc.frequency.value = 200;
osc.start(0)

//Osc2 should modify the filter's frequency value.

var osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc2.connect(filter.frequency);
osc2.frequency.value = 1;
osc2.start(0)
```

Does anyone know how to make this work, or perhaps there is some other work around?

Thanks!

Comment: I've successfully connected oscillators to gain nodes, or to frequency on oscillator nodes, but like you, I've had trouble connecting oscillators to a filter's frequency, or other audioParams. I'm not sure what the problem is.